# PostgreSQL optimization: average over range of dates

Tags: postgresql, optimization, moving-average

I have a query (with a subquery) that calculates an average of temperatures over the previous years, plus/minus one week per each day. It works, but it is not all that fast. The time series values below are just an example. Why I'm using `doy` is because I want a sliding window around the same date for every year.

```
SELECT days,
    (SELECT avg(temperature)
     FROM temperatures
     WHERE site_id = ? AND
      extract(doy FROM timestamp) BETWEEN
      extract(doy FROM days) - 7 AND extract(doy FROM days) + 7
    ) AS temperature
FROM generate_series('2017-05-01'::date, '2017-08-31'::date, interval '1 day') days
```

So my question is, could this query somehow be improved? I was thinking about using some kind of window function or possibly `lag` and `lead`. However at least regular window functions only work on specific amount of rows, whereas there can be any number of measurements within the two-week window.

I can live with what I have for now, but as the amount of data grows so does the execution speed of the query. The two latter `extract`s could be removed, but that has no noticeable speed improvement and only makes the query less legible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for the term "sargable" and I suggest providing an explain plan for your existing query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best index for your original query is

```
create index idx_temperatures_site_id_timestamp_doy
  on temperatures(site_id, extract(doy from timestamp));
```

This can greatly improve your original query's performance.

While your original query is simple & readable, it has 1 flaw: it will calculate every day's average 14 times (on average). Instead, you could calculate these averages on a daily basis & calculate the 2 week window's weighted average (the weight for a day's average needs to be count of the individual rows in your original table). Something like this:

```
with p as (
  select timestamp '2017-05-01' min,
         timestamp '2017-08-31' max
)
select     t.*
from       p
cross join (select     days, sum(sum(temperature)) over pn1week / sum(count(temperature)) over pn1week
            from       p
            cross join generate_series(min - interval '1 week', max + interval '1 week', interval '1 day') days
            left join  temperatures on site_id = ? and extract(doy from timestamp) = extract(doy from days)
            group by   days
            window     pn1week as (order by days rows between 7 preceding and 7 following)) t
where      days between min and max
order by   days
```

However, there is not much gain here, as this is only twice as fast as your original query (with the optimal index).

http://rextester.com/JCAG41071

**Notes**: I used `timestamp` because I assumed your column's type is `timestamp`. But as it turned out, you use `timestamptz` (aka. `timestamp with time zone`). With that type, you cannot index the `extract(doy from timestamp)` expression, because [that expression's output is dependent of the actual client's time zone setting](http://rextester.com/XYKM90657).

For `timestamptz` use an index which (at least) starts with `site_id`. Using the window version should improve the performance anyway.

http://rextester.com/XTJSM42954

Comment: An interesting approach, and certainly much faster than my original one. My initial attempt was indeed indexing the table on `doy` but that does not work because apparently `extract doy` is not immutable. In any case, this works much much faster with the data I have.

Comment: @TeemuKarimerto that's because your column is actually `timestamptz`. Please see my edits (at **notes**).

Comment: Ah yes, that seems to be the issue with the indexing. I would prefer to use `timestamp` but these are all Django-generated tables and I'm not entirely sure how I ought to go about possibly converting the values in the database AND configuring Django so nothing breaks :D

Comment: It seems like trying to force Django to use timestamps without time zones is a bad idea. So I'm just going to skip the `doy`-based indexing and go with this query as it is certainly much faster than my original one.